# SonataAdmin create entity with boolean field

Tags: symfony, symfony4, sonata-admin

I have this entity, if I create a record like this.

```
$synopsis = new Synopsis();
$synopsis->setPartOne("a");
$synopsis->setPartTwo("b");
$synopsis->setTitle("A");
$synopsis->setSubtitle("B");
$synopsis->setEnabled(false);

$em->persist($synopsis);
$em->flush();
```

And then I go to my Admin, I see the enabled field to "no" which is expected.

But now, If I use the sonata admin new form field, even if I choose enabled "no", the record is created with enabled = true. And I don't really see why it would be like that.

Here is what I have in my SynopsisAdmin

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper->add('title', TextType::class);
    $formMapper->add('subtitle', TextType::class);
    $formMapper->add('partOne', TextAreaType::class);
    $formMapper->add('partTwo', TextAreaType::class);
    $formMapper->add('enabled', BooleanType::class);
}
```

This is how the enabled field is defined in the entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $enabled;
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Fun facts too, even if I see no in the sonata view list, when I go to the form view, I see yes instead.

I suspect an error within the sonata core functionnality.

Comment: Does the same thing  happen when you switch out BooleanType for example 'CheckboxType' ?

Comment: @Jeroen Looks like no, it works with CheckBoxType, which is fine for me. But still that means there is a bug on the BooleanType

Comment: Don't think the BooleanType is meant to be used in the formmapper...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use the `CheckboxType` instead of the `BooleanType` for your Form fields.

Looks like the `BooleanType` is ment for the list, show and grid actions.
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/field_types.html

**Update**

To use the BooleanType you have to set the 'transform' option to `true`.
This transforms your boolean value to the YES/NO options in the BooleanType:

```
$formMapper
    ->add('enabled', BooleanType::class, [
           'transform' => true
    ])
```

Comment: We will see, I still have sent it as a bug into their github, I will see. Thanks anyway.